# Do I need to play DQ4 before DQ5?

Tags: dragon-quest-series

I own both Dragon Quest IV and Dragon Quest V, but I am more interested in playing DQ5. I know the two are in some kind of trilogy, but I’m not sure if they are directly related or only have loose tie-ins (like DQ1 and DQ2). Will I miss out on any story details by playing DQ5 first?

I’m looking for a list of whatever I might miss, but WITHOUT SPOILERS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DQ4, 5 and 6, are set at least one thousand years apart from one another, to the point that even the world maps are different. The "trilogy's" only real connections are the Zenithian race and the 'legendary equipment' the heroes equip.

You are totally okay with playing them separately and out of order.

You can read more about DQ as a whole [here](https://www.rpgsite.net/feature/5866-the-complete-beginner-s-guide-to-dragon-quest-part-1-main-titles) if you're looking for more information on which games to play and which ones are related in some way.